# Торчат некоторые участки модели

Tags: model, blender, fbx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток! У меня нарисовалась такая проблемка - на скрине видно, как выпирает часть модели через другую. Вопрос, можно ли как то  ровно сгладить, устранить это выпирание? Использую Blender

Comment: При чем здесь unity?

Comment: Я без понятия почему вопрос в юнити3д зашел